# Do server-sent events work with CORS?

Tags: html, google-chrome, push-notification, cors, server-sent-events

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events):

> Note: Although it's not yet part of the standard, EventSource supports CORS in Firefox 11 and later. This is expected to become standard soon.

Does anybody know the current status of this? Is this still true? What about Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some experiments, and as it seems, server-sent events do work on current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari out of the box with CORS :-).

I did not test Opera, and I did not test Internet Explorer (which, according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/eventsource)) is not capable of server-sent events.

Comment: But there are some polyfills for other browsers https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource

Comment: Note that the polyfill mentioned has added some questionable code that any reader or user would need to be aware of: https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/issues/202

There are alternatives such as https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource

Comment: IMHO the same applies there as well: https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource#extensions-to-the-w3c-api